# Help with asp.net membership in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I need two things that the Membership Provider I'm sure is capable of doing.
Firstly I need to initially set users that have just registered to have a IsApproved value of False.

Obviously I also need an admin to be able to change that status to true.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create your custom provider.
Just register the users manually using the MembershipProvider API.

```
public abstract MembershipUser MembershipProvider.CreateUser(
    string username,
    string password,
    string email,
    string passwordQuestion,
    string passwordAnswer,
    bool isApproved,
    Object providerUserKey,
    out MembershipCreateStatus status
)
```

MembershipUser has an IsApproved property.
Your admins can use:

```
MembershipProvider.UpdateUser(MembershipUser);
```

to approve them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it does not support that.  You'd have to write your own custom provider to do that.  Though, writing your own for SQL is not terribly complex and heavily documented in multiple places throughout the blogesphere.

Comment: Yes Nick is correct see here
http://thekevincode.com/2010/09/adding-email-confirmation-to-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Nick, it's not necessary to create a custom provider to do that. Refer to my answer.

Comment: Daveo, thats an interesting article..the only thing I dont completely like is the fact that you are updating a model through a GET request... but I guess theres no way around it for this case.

Comment: @SantiagoIT - You learn something new every day.  Thanks for enlightening me.